# Trouble loading PHP Class within the same project

Tags: php, html, class, import, autoload

Someone could help me on the issue of referencing php files within the same project (calling classes) using "namespace","use" ( php v5.3 or higher) [My Screenshoot][https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpqTn.png

```
Zoho\
 CRM\
  Common\
      -HttpClientInterface.php
  Config\
  Entities\
  Exception\
  Request\
  Wrapper\
  index.php
```

I've read about autoloading classes but I don't undersand very well..

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zoho\CRM\Common\HttpClientInterface' not found in C:\root\zohocrm-master\src\Zoho\CRM\index.php on line 73


<?php namespace Zoho\CRM;

    use Zoho\CRM\Common\HttpClientInterface;
    use Zoho\CRM\Common\FactoryInterface;
    use Zoho\CRM\Request\HttpClient;
    use Zoho\CRM\Request\Factory;
    use Zoho\CRM\Wrapper\Element;    
                    .
                    .
                    .

    public function __construct($authtoken, HttpClientInterface $client =null , FactoryInterface $factory = null )
            {
                $this->authtoken = $authtoken;
                // Only XML format is supported for the time being
                $this->format = 'xml'; 


                 $this->client = new HttpClientInterface();
                $this->factory = $factory ;
                $this->module = "Leads";
                return $this;
            }
```

This is my class file :

```
<?php namespace Zoho\CRM\Common;

/**
 * Common interface for Http clients
 *
 * @package Zoho\CRM\Common
 * @version 1.0.0
 */
interface HttpClientInterface
{
  /**
   * Performs POST request.
   *
   * @param string $uri Direction to make the post
   * @param string $postBody Post data
   */
  public function post($uri, $postBody);
}
```

Comment: From first glance it would look like it isn't finding the file, but perhaps it isn't looking in the right place.  Can you post your autoloader implementation?

Comment: <code>function __autoload($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
}
</code>
 ... :/

Comment: What I would do is confirm that `$class_name` is pointing to the correct file.  If you are autoloading, you should work relative from the file that is doing the autoloading.  It looks like you are already in the `Zoho\CRM` directory, so make sure your autoloader works from there.  You can always `echo $class_name` inside your autoloader function just to get a quick idea of what file is trying to be autoloaded.

Comment: I think that my autoloading code is wrong. Because it doesn't appear anything(echo $class name) when I put it on index.php
 :(

Comment: You would put that statement in your `__autoload()` function.  Inside your `index.php` file will not help.  Again, based on your error message I think you looking in a non-existent directory.

Comment: "echo $class_name" is inside autoload() function .....
my file directorty http://i.imgur.com/6GC4UUK.png?1